# How to start activty on recycler view item click?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley, start-activity

I am feteching data from server using JSON and showing that data in recycler view. But the problem is I may need to add some new data to the server.
 Using volley, request will be send to server and recycler view list will be updated. So the problem is I want to open new activity on each recycler view item click. But my recycler view list will increase if I added some new data to the server. So, I can't change layout/start activity based on itemclick postion.
Is there any better way to implement this?

Just like whatsapp, I want to open new activity/fragment on itemclick of recycler view.

This what I tried to do but this is not proper way. Coz I don't know how many item will be present inside recyclerview. Here is my code:

```
private final Context context;

public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    context = itemView.getContext();

}

   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {          

    final Intent intent;
    switch (getAdapterPostion()){
        case 0:
           intent =  new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
           break;

        case 1:
            intent =  new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
            break;
           ...
        default:
           intent =  new Intent(context, DefaultActivity.class);
           break;
     }
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You can add the getAdapterPostion() int into the intent using putExtra and then retrieve it within the Activity and make changes within the Activity based of the int?

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to replicate the functionality of WhatsApp pay attention that when you click on an item on a list the app will not open a new Activity, it will open the same Activity sending different data to load the data for that specific user.

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Chat.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_USER_ID", userId);
startActivity(intent);
...
```

On the Chat.class

```
...
Intent intent = getIntent();
String userId = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_USER_ID");
...
```

Using this user id you can load data for this specific user.

Comment: But how to get particular data if i clicked on particular item in list view ?

Answer (score 0):

a proper approach is using an interface in your adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<Item> items;
    private final OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(Item item);
    }

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public void bind (final Item item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {

            yourclickableView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onItemClick(item);
                }
            });
        }
    }

public MyAdapter(List<Item> items, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        ...
        this.listener = listener;
        items = items;
    }
```

and finally:

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(items.get(position), listener);
        ...
    }
```

and whenever using your adapter class:

```
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter (itemsList, new MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override 
                public void onItemClick(Item item) {
                  //bluh bluh...
                }
            });
```